# i have installed postfix and dovecot and squirrelmail and apache configured , but i can't send email to any external server

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, squirrelmail

I have installed and configured an email client `SquirrelMail`, I have also installed `Postfix` and `Dovecot` and also `Apache` ( **because my app is running on `Nginx` , i had to put the apache on port `81`**) , and I have configured them.

> but I can only send and/or receive emails internally, from my user@mydomain.com to usertwo@mydomain.com
>
> I can not receive or send any email to an external server like google and such

for example, when I try to send email to google from `SquirrelMail`, I get

```
Message not sent. Server replied:
Temporary authentication failure
454 4.7.1 <arash.internet@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

and when I try to send email from `Gmail` to myuser@mydomain.com, **The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [mail.shianchi.com. 45.82.138.110: FAILED_PRECONDITION: connect error (111): Connection refused] [mail2.shianchi.com. 45.82.138.110: FAILED_PRECONDITION: connect error (111): Connection refused]** , but I don't see any email in that user inbox in which I sent the email to.

it has frustrated me, I don't know what to do
please someone help me :(
thank you beforehand

Comment: What are you using for authentication? I found configuring email to be very difficult. I think many people agree and will suggest patience will be needed. The following article had some helpful advice for trouble shooting. https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/troubleshooting-problems-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks Phil for your answer , i didn't use any special authentication . i know that i'm using `smpt` , and i know the server name is `mail.mydomain.com` and i get the ip with ifconfig , and i setted the ip of `mail.mydomain.com` to be exactly that ip that i get using ifconfig `which is the ip of the system` , other than that , i just watched this video and i followed it spets https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r91lEOGtpvs , can you please help me by watching some of it ? please

Comment: can this error arises from changing the `port` or `apache` to `81` , i go to `SquirrelMail WebMail` by going to the address **http://45.82.138.110:81/webmail/** , and the **45.82.128.110** part , is also the same ip that i have for `mail.mydomain.com , and the **81** part , is because i used `NginX` on 80 , so **81** is the port for my `httpd , Apache`

Comment: It took me weeks to get my email working. I'm not going to go through that again if I don't have to. It's too complicated and my understanding is too weak! I asked about auth because of the message saying that authentication had failed. I used https://certbot.eff.org/ (CertBot). As far as ports, I stuck with the standard ports and recommend the same. If you do anything unusual, remember that you have to your firewall configured to allow that port to work. Most firewall configs default to blocking unless an explicit rule says traffic can pass on that port.